# Eclipse writes unknown target when I connect my asus tablet with android 4.4.2

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to test my android programs and I need test my programs in my android tablet my tablet is ASUS f2375cg with android 4.4.2.when I connect my tablet to my laptop through usb(my laptop is asus k43sv with win7),Eclipse can  recognize my tablet but writes unknown target
[image]

I did all of this setting in my tablet
1-I checked usb debugging option
2- I checked Media device(MTP)
3-I also installed my tablet usb drive

but I still I'am getting that error how can I fix that.I also should mention that I tried all of this things that I listed below
1-I rebooted my tablet and connected to my laptop through different usb port.
2-I killed adb.exe process and closed Eclipse an run it again.
3-I taped again on (Revoke USB debugging authorization) button when I reconnected my tablet to my laptop.
4-I uninstalled my tablet usb drive and installed it again.

Thanks in advance spending your time to help me.

[image]

Comment: It may be given a popup of grant usb debugging for your computer . Is it coming ?

Comment: I can access to my removal sd  card and my internal sd card and ask me at first what to do but still I have that problem